# How to silence and restore ringer automatically in android?

Tags: android

I want to ask user for specific time period in which android phone will get silent automatically an after that time period it will ring normally. I know basic for making a phone silent/ringer from audio manager but I can not figure out How I can achieve whole task ?

I think to achieve this my app must always run in background like alarm app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app should utilize PendingIntent + AlarmManager to achieve your goal. And It is not necessary to make it run in background. The main logic may like this:

1. get silent time from user
2. silent the phone via AudioManager
3. calculate ring time based on current time and inputted period
4. create a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast in ring time
5. get AlarmManager service and set the alarm time to ring time
6. restore ring mode in broadcast receiver.

Comment: thanks Scott Sun for explaining the logic and structure